# Checkbox filter products with jquery and keep state with reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a page where I can filter products with checkboxes but also to keep the filter choices on page reload.

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline ">
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="option1" >
<label for="1">Adidas</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline ">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="option2" >
<label for="1">Nike</label>
</div>

<script>
    var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });

  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.products >div').hide();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.products >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']').show();
        });
    } else {
        $('.products >div').show();

    }
});
</script>
```

I have found both jquery scripts and they both work fine by themselves. By this I mean that I can get to filter the products when checking/unchecking the checkboxes. When checking a checkbox and reloading the page, the checkbox is correctly checked but products has not been filtered. So I need to merge the 2 scripts so that products also will be filtered when reloading the page with a checked checkbox.

Hope someone can guide me a bit here.

--- UPDATE ---

I have created an example here: maxie.dk/filter.php

1) Tick a checkbox

2) Product filter is activated and only products with matching value is   displayed

3) Refresh page

4) Checkbox checked is kept as it should but all products are now again visible. Only matching products to the ticked checkbox should be visible.

Thanks

Comment: More explanation is needed here.

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining thorough enough.

I have created an example here: http://maxie.dk/filter.php

1) Tick a checkbox
2) Product filter is activated and only products with matching value is displayed
3) Refresh page
4) Checkbox checked is kept as it should but all products are shown. Only matching products should be visible

Answer (score 0):

If I get your issue right - you want to move your "business logic" that happens on each input change to a separate function so that it can be executed also upon page reload.

```
...
// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});

// your business logic
function updateProducts() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.products >div').hide();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('.products >div[data-category=' + this.id + ']').show();
        });
    } else {
        $('.products >div').show();

    }
}

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    // execute for each change
    updateProducts();
});

// execute on page load
updateProducts()
```

Comment: Hi @Peter
Thanks for the answer. I have tried using your script but this does not work as expected. As you also state, what I want to accomplish is having a page initially with all products listed (and checkboxes unchecked). When a checkbox is ticked, only products with the ticked checkboxes data value in attribute will be shown. When user refreshes page, the ticked checkboxes are remembered as well as only the products with checked data value in attribute will be shown. http//www.maxie.dk/filter2.php

Answer (score 0):

I have re-write this such that it will update the localstorage and also check and show product that is save in localstorage. It will also remove or show product on checked. Check it out.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="breadcrumb" id="checkbox-container">
    <h4 class="visible-xs"></h4>
    <span class="hidden-xs"></span>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" />
      <label for="1">Adidas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" />
      <label for="2">Reebok</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline ">
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" /> <label for="3">Nike</label>
    </div>

    ´
  </div>
</div>

<div class="products">
  <div
    class="col-xs-6 col-ms-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 padding-btm "
    data-category="1" >
    PRODUCT 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="products">
  <div
    class="col-xs-6 col-ms-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 padding-btm "
    data-category="1">
    PRODUCT 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="products">
  <div
    class="col-xs-6 col-ms-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 padding-btm "
    data-category="2"
  >
    PRODUCT 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="products">
  <div
    class="col-xs-6 col-ms-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 padding-btm "
    data-category="3"
  >
    PRODUCT 4
  </div>
</div>


var checkedValues =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || [],
      $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container input[type=checkbox]");

        function loadPrevious(){
           if(checkedValues.length>0){
            $("div.products > div").hide();
                $.each(checkedValues,function(i,v){
                     $("#checkbox-container input[type=checkbox]#" + v ).prop('checked',true);
                     $('.products >div[data-category=' + v + ']').show();
                })
           }

      }

    loadPrevious();

    $checkboxes.change(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
           checkedValues.push($(this).attr("id"));
            loadPrevious();
           localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkedValues));               
      }else{
           var checkId = $(this).attr("id"),
           arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues'));
           $('.products >div[data-category=' + checkId + ']').hide();
           var newArr = $(arr).not([checkId]).get();
            localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(newArr));               
      }
    });
```

See the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mark2kk/xpvt214o/962431/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried updating my example (maxie.dk/filter.php) with your script, but this does not work. The filter does not respond on first tick in a checkbox and also when refreshing the page the products are reset to show all products. Could you have a look?

Comment: Check the jsFiddle sample

Comment: Yes - very close @Mark. I am trying to reverse the logic with the checkboxes in your script so initially none is ticked but ALL products are shown. Only when activating/ticking the first checkbox, the sorting starts. I can't get your script to do so.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to hide all products until checkbox is checked. If that is what you want then why do you now save checked history to localstorage?

Comment: I do not want to hide products. I want the opposite. I want all products to be shown when page is initially loaded. When user ticks a checkbox only products with data-attribute value from checkbox is visible.

What I want to accomplish is having a page initially with all products listed (and checkboxes unchecked). When a checkbox is ticked, only products with the ticked checkboxes data value in attribute will be shown. When user refreshes page, the ticked checkboxes are remembered as well as only the products with checked data value in attribute will be shown.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. I have updated the jsFiddle. Check it now. Dont forget to mark as answer if you think its ok

Comment: Hi @mark
No, unfortunately it still does not work as I want. All 4 products must be visible when no checkbox is checked. So initially all products are visible. When checking first checkbox, products with this data attribute value will only be shown, all other will hide. When checkbox 1 and 2 is checked, products with data attribute value 1 or 2 will be visible, all other hidden. and so on.